# Como mostrar apenas registos com um caractere ou letra associada para limitar a pesquisa?

Tags: php, mysql

O código abaixo mostra os registos que incluam o número inicial que foi digitado até ao limite de 5 (1, 11, 19, 107, 115...). Sendo que o campo a pesquisar tem artigos numerados com a palavra "Artigo" como padrão (Artigo 107.º -, Artigo 107.º-A -, etc), como mostrar só os registos com o número digitado, por exemplo 107, e também os que tenham uma letra maiúscula, mantendo o limite de 5 (exemplo: Artigo 107.º -, Artigo 107.º-A -, Artigo 107.º-B -, Artigo 107.º-C -, Artigo 107.º- D)???

```
<?php 
include 'conn.php';

$letter = $_GET["letter"];

$sql = "SELECT id,palavra from interpretacao_cpp where pronta != 0 AND palavra LIKE '".$letter."%' ORDER BY id asc limit 5" ;

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTR(`palavra`, 1, 1)) As abc from interpretacao_cpp where pronta != 0 ORDER BY abc";

$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);

?>
```

Comment: Todos os registros ja tem a palavra "Artigo" como padrão?

Comment: Sim, todos os registos têm a palavra "Artigo". Ou existe só o número com a palavra Artigo, por exemplo Artigo 107.º -, ou então pode existir um ou mais números directamente relacionados que têm a palavra Artigo e a respectiva letra maiúscula em sequencia (A, B, C...), por exemplo Artigo 107.º-A -, Artigo 107.º-B -, etc. Para que exista uma das letras maiúsculas num registo e a sua sequência tem de primeiro existir apenas o artigo ou numero principal (sem nenhuma letra), e portanto a sequência é sempre Artigo 107.º -, Artigo 107.º-A -, Artigo 107.º-B -, ... etc.

Comment: Não se se entendi a questão mas deu a entender que se o usuário digitar `107` então ele obtém `107.º -, Artigo 107.º-A -, Artigo 107.º-B -, ... etc`. Se for na primeira consulta troque a clausula `LIKE '".$letter."%'` por `LIKE '%".$letter."%' .

Comment: Se usar isto - `LIKE '%".$letter."%'  - dá erro de unespected t_sting  reportado à linha 12 em: $sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTR(`palavra`, 1, 1)) As abc from dicionario_penal where pronta != 0 ORDER BY abc";